# mysql update count query with multiple join subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

Morning,
I am trying to create a count of products per category / store using an UPDATE, JOIN, SUBQUERY but I cant get the syntax right, can someone help me where I am going wrong:

```
UPDATE 
    oc_category_to_store c2s 
SET 
    c2s.product_count = 
        (
        SELECT 
            count(p.product_id) as product_count,
            p2c.category_id,
            p2s.store_id
        FROM 
            oc_product p
            INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c ON 
                (p.product_id = p2c.product_id)
            INNER JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON
                (p.product_id = p2s.product_id)
        ) AS pc
WHERE
        (p2c.category_id = pc.category_id) AND
        (p2s.store_id = pc.store_id)
```

Essentially this is in OpenCart but the existing product count routines are done in PHP are on large DBs of products it slows the site down to a crawl.

products are linked to both categories and stores by ID using the product_to_category and product_to_store tables, categories and also linked to stores using a category_to_store table.

I want to run a mySQL query to update the product counts per category / store by storing the value in the category_to_store table as this only needs to run when products are added / deleted / updated and not every time any page loads.

```
CREATE TABLE `oc_product_to_category` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AVG_ROW_LENGTH=9 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;

CREATE TABLE `oc_product_to_store` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`store_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AVG_ROW_LENGTH=9 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;

CREATE TABLE `oc_category_to_store` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`store_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AVG_ROW_LENGTH=9 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;
```

Comment: Can you post your table schema and perhaps clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have added to the original post.

Comment: Can the same `product_id` be present in both `oc_product_to_store` and `oc_product_to_category` tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `INNER JOIN` syntax:

```
UPDATE 
    oc_category_to_store a
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        b.category_id,
        c.store_id,
        COUNT(*) AS productcnt
    FROM 
        oc_product a
    INNER JOIN
        oc_product_to_category b ON a.product_id = b.product_id
    INNER JOIN
        oc_product_to_store c ON a.product_id = c.product_id
    GROUP BY
        b.category_id,
        c.store_id
) b ON 
    a.category_id = b.category_id AND 
    a.store_id = b.store_id
SET
    a.product_count = b.productcnt
```

Comment: Wow, never thought of it like that: thanks Zane, 39 - 40 seconds down to 203 milliseconds :) Perfect.  Thanks once again, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The 1st error is in your query logic. Your subquery returns 3 columns:

```
product_count,
p2c.category_id,
p2s.store_id
```

And you're trying to assign this triple to a single column *c2s.product_count*

UPDATE

The 2nd error is in the WHERE clause of your main query. You use tables *p2c*, *p2s* and *pc*
however UPDATE clause utilizes *c2s* only. The most likely the WHERE clause must be in the subquery like below:

```
UPDATE 
    oc_category_to_store c2s 
SET 
    c2s.product_count = 
        (
        SELECT 
            count(oc_product.product_id) as product_count,
        FROM 
            oc_product p
            INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c ON 
                (p.product_id = p2c.product_id)
            INNER JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON
                (p.product_id = p2s.product_id)
        WHERE
            (p2c.category_id = pc.category_id) AND
            (p2s.store_id = pc.store_id)        
        )
```

Comment: @ Maksym: yes I see that now, thanks. However removing the additional two columns still produces a syntax error.
@ Zane: yes, all products are assigned to both a category and a store, and the categories / stores are linked as well.

Comment: thanks so much for your suggestion.  The query at least runs now, however my mySQL client comes back and says: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
(42.578 sec)

Comment: I noticed that in the part:
(p2c.category_id = pc.category_id) AND
(p2s.store_id = pc.store_id)
The references to table pc, needed to be c2s instead

Comment: Running in phpmyadmin it now works: 1352 rows affected. ( Query took 43.2362 sec )
Is there anyway to improve on the speed do you think?

Comment: @user1494034, it's probably running slow because it is executing the subquery for each row in `oc_category_to_store` as it is correlated. Try the `INNER JOIN` solution.

Comment: @user1494034 add indexes for every field you use in joins and where.

Comment: @MaksymPolshcha ah right, yes I understand.  Indexes are already there, all the tables have the columns in their primary index.  When you say "try the INNER JOIN" solution do you mean move the criteria for the WHERE clause inside the respective INNER JOIN for that table?